# Flutter Speech To Text is not working on Android

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

After I run the source code, it doesn't seem there are errors in speech recognition but it does give warnings on deprecation issues. Can anyone who has any idea on this issue help me? I have no idea to settle this. I've been banging my head thinking for this solution and keep changing the plugin to try out every possible solution. Thank you in advance.

Below is the debug console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(23764): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54086/5SFyrXlWPbo=/ws
D/EGL_emulation(23764): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1005b40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc63ef010)
I/OpenGLRenderer(23764): Davey! duration=7183ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=120809744677502, Vsync=120814844677298, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=120814867298760, AnimationStart=120814884416860, PerformTraversalsStart=120814981718460, DrawStart=120816317099660, SyncQueued=120816631755960, SyncStart=120816958353760, IssueDrawCommandsStart=120816979574560, SwapBuffers=120817095741560, FrameCompleted=120817254727060, DequeueBufferDuration=105300000, QueueBufferDuration=5063000,
D/eglCodecCommon(23764): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/OpenGLRenderer(23764): Davey! duration=935ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=120840030058709, Vsync=120840346725363, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=120840356603560, AnimationStart=120840368806860, PerformTraversalsStart=120840729392360, DrawStart=120840794494960, SyncQueued=120840818237460, SyncStart=120840822394960, IssueDrawCommandsStart=120840828390560, SwapBuffers=120840893817960, FrameCompleted=120840970046060, DequeueBufferDuration=12527000, QueueBufferDuration=45393000,
```

I'm using this plugin: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/speech_to_text/

My code for Android is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _lastWords = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
  void _startListening() async {
    await _speechToText.listen(onResult: _onSpeechResult);
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  void _stopListening() async {
    await _speechToText.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text(
                'Recognized words:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  // If listening is active show the recognized words
                  _speechToText.isListening
                      ? '$_lastWords'
                      // If listening isn't active but could be tell the user
                      // how to start it, otherwise indicate that speech
                      // recognition is not yet ready or not supported on
                      // the target device
                      : _speechEnabled
                          ? 'Tap the microphone to start listening...'
                          : 'Speech not available',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
            // If not yet listening for speech start, otherwise stop
            _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It does beep but when it does not show any output afterwards. Also in the AndroidManifest.xml in main and debug folder I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: I think maybe the problem is on my laptop bcs there is no problem that occurred after I linked my phone to flutter vscode.

Answer (score 0):

FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(23764): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.

I think, the problem not in speech to text. The compiler swears at some splash screen. And judging by the error, it has nothing to do with speech_to_text. Do you have any other dependencies in your project? If yes, then you should check them out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35139607)